# AngularJS Routes and ASP.NET MVC Routes To Coexist with $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am using AngularJS with ASP.NET MVC 5 and have $locationProvider.html5Mode set to true. Is it possible for angularJS routes and ASP.NET MVC routes to coexist with $locationProvider.html5Mode set to true. I am trying to access a MVC route(route defined in RouteConfig.cs) when I am in a view in AngularJS route, but the page never shows up. If I try to copy and paste the link in the browser and access it then it shows. When $locationProvider.html5Mode is set to false, that is when route uses #, I can access both angularJS routes and ASP.NET MVC routes. Is there a way to make it work when $locationProvider.html5Mode=true or do I set it to false if I want both route types to coexists.

Comment: For others who have similar concerns, here is an article I found that solved my problem. https://web.archive.org/web/20150704231348/http://www.jlum.ws/post/2014/10/10/handling-routes-between-an-angularjs-application-and-aspnet-mvc-application